# Kindle Fire Tablet 2.3.4: Videoview getting black in android on touching other part of the screen.

Tags: android, android-videoview, kindle-fire

I have a RelativeLayout inside that added an imageview and have added a videoview to this relative layout. I am running the video from my sd card path. Its all working perfectly fine on all other devices like Samsung tab 7inch, 10inch but I am available with Kindle Fire with android version 2.3.4. The moment I touch and drag my finger on anywhere on the screen (including videoview area and other area) it turns into black color and if I again do the same thing it comes back, though i can still hear the sound. Any Help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code

```
play.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { 
@Override 
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) { 
Log.v("Layer Data draw", "ONPREPARE"); 
//if(getAutoplay()) 
play.start(); 
SystemClock.sleep(300); // parent.removeView(frame);
Toast.makeText(con.getApplicationContext(), "The val is :: ",    
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); frame.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
} });
```

Comment: Show some code to move on further.

Comment: this is the code snap, the way i am starting the video play.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
     Log.v("Layer Data draw", "ONPREPARE");
     // if(getAutoplay())
     play.start();
     SystemClock.sleep(300);
     // parent.removeView(frame);
     Toast.makeText(con.getApplicationContext(), "The val is :: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     frame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
   });

Comment: edit your question and paste the code there, its complicated in the comment area.

Comment: @Jibran Khan : its done